# How to add a value to arraylist in android?

Tags: android

I am **adding a value to my arraylist** but it is showing error. Before adding the value I am displaying it first. The value is displaying but it is not adding to the arraylist. Please help me regarding this...

My Code:

```
static ArrayList<String> allfirstids;

ArrayList<String> list = List.get(i);
UserBO user = new UserBO();

user.firstid = Integer.parseInt(list.get(0));
user.secondid = Integer.parseInt(list.get(1));
System.out.print("Hello this is first id");
System.out.print(list.get(0));

allfirstids.add(list.get(0));
System.out.println("first ids"+allfirstids);
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: it is showing error? what error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

before adding, please initialize arraylist.

```
 allfirstids = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Comment: Hi I made very silly mistake by not initializing arraylist....thank you..now its working....

Comment: Hi everytime when I call the page the list.get(0) contains different value. For suppose first time list.get(0)=10 then first 10 is added...again second time in list.get(0) = 20 then it is replacing the 10...But I want to add 10,20,...to my arraylist. How can I do that?

Comment: dont initialize allfirstids inside loop. it will reinitialize always and add the recent data. If you can post the complete method, i can tell you what exactly you have to do

Comment: if it is inside a method, you can also do like this. put condition while initializing arraylist

if(allfirstids == null) {
allfirstids = new ArrayList<String>();}

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to initialize your static `ArrayList allfirstids`, Just initialize it, before using..

```
static ArrayList<String> allfirstids = new ArrayList<String>();

ArrayList<String> list = List.get(i);
UserBO user = new UserBO();

user.firstid = Integer.parseInt(list.get(0));
user.secondid = Integer.parseInt(list.get(1));
System.out.print("Hello this is first id");
System.out.print(list.get(0));

allfirstids.add(list.get(0));
System.out.println("first ids"+allfirstids);
```